# How to compute weighted average in python for large corpus?

Tags: python, gensim, tf-idf, weighted-average

I have large corpus of sentences ~22GB. I would like to represent each sentence as a weighted average of word2vecs. So far I have

```
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary, HashDictionary, MmCorpus, WikiCorpus, TextCorpus
from gensim.models import TfidfModel
from gensim.matutils import sparse2full

dictionary = HashDictionary(id_range=DEFAULT_DICT_SIZE, debug=True)
dictionary.allow_update = True  # start collecting document frequencies
text_corpus = LogCorpus(inp_dir, dictionary=dictionary,metadata=False)

MmCorpus.serialize( str(inp_dir)+'bow.mm', text_corpus, progress_cnt=10000, metadata=False)
# with HashDictionary, the token->id mapping is only fully instantiated now, after `serialize`
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=20, no_above=0.1, keep_n=DEFAULT_DICT_SIZE)
dictionary.save_as_text(str(inp_dir)+'wordids.txt.bz2')
text_corpus.save(str(inp_dir)+'corpus.pkl.bz2')
dictionary.allow_update = False
    
# initialize corpus reader and word->id mapping
mm = MmCorpus(str(inp_dir)+'bow.mm')

# build tfidf
tfidf = TfidfModel(mm, id2word=dictionary, normalize=True)
tfidf.save(str(inp_dir)+'tfidf.tfidf_model')

# save tfidf vectors in matrix market format
docs_tfidf = tfidf[mm]
MmCorpus.serialize(str(inp_dir)+'tfidf.mm', docs_tfidf, progress_cnt=10000)

dense_representation = np.vstack([sparse2full(c, len(dictionary)) for c in docs_tfidf])
```

which is pretty much copy of the https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/scripts/make_wiki_online.py

However dense_representation has dimension of len(dictionary) which for HashDictionary is huge.

How can I proceed to use those weights and combine them with word2vecs?

Comment: Why can you not do it like if it was not huge?

Comment: Why have you added a step to convert the sparse matrices to very-wide dense vectors? If your (unshown) `DEFAULT_DICT_SIZE` is anything like the code you've used as a model (10000) that's likely to be a gigantic expansion of memory usage for unclear or no reason. Separately, where's the set of word2vec vectors you intend to use? (Do you want to train them from your texts?)

Comment: @mkrieger1 because I have to use HashDictionary instead of Dictionary to be able to update it sequentally. Afaik it is not possible to do it with normal Dictionary.

Comment: @gojomo I did it because it is the only way to use sparse2full on words tfidfed with HashDictionary, they have indicies all over the place from 0 to the DEFAULT_DICT_SIZE